# Reactjs IF statement

Tags: reactjs, string, function, if-statement

I have a component I call that is a passed a recordID and returns the text associated to the Id.  33 should = Tower

will render "Tower" on the screen. All good, but...

When I try to use the component in the following IF statement it does not work.

...

```
if (<GetAssetTypeNameComponent datafromparent = {assettype_assettypeId}/> === "Tower")
{ 
    this.props.history.push(`/add-assetstower/${assetsid}/${this.props.match.params.sitemasterid}`);
}
```

Using the passed parameter does work if I change the code to:

...

```
if (assettype_assettypeId === "33")
        { 
            this.props.history.push(`/add-assetstower/${assetsid}/${this.props.match.params.sitemasterid}`);
        }
```

...

What am I doing wrong?

Rob

Component Code that needs to be a Function....
...

```
class GetAssetTypeNameComponent extends Component {
    constructor (props){
        super(props)
         this.state = {
             assettype:[]
        }
    }

    componentDidMount()
    {
        AssetTypeService.getAssetTypeById(this.props.datafromparent).then( (res) =>{
            let assettype = res.data;
            this.setState({isLoading:false});
            this.setState({
                assettypeName: assettype.assettypeName,
                assettypeType: assettype.assettypeType
            });
        });

      
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
               {this.state.assettypeName}  
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default GetAssetTypeNameComponent;
```

...
Following Function code compiles:
...

```
import React, { useState} from 'react';
import AssetTypeService from './AssetTypeService'

    const GetAssetTypeNameFunction = (props) =>{
  // destructuring 
      const { assettype_assettypeId } = props;
      const [assetType,setAssetType] = useState()
    
    AssetTypeService.getAssetTypeById(assettype_assettypeId).then( (res) =>
    setAssetType(res.data));

const arrayMap = assetType.map((post)=>{
return(
       <ul> 
           {post.assettypeName}  
        </ul>
);})

    return (
        {arrayMap}
    );
}
export default GetAssetTypeNameFunction;
```

...
Get execution error:
I think because I calling the function from within an eventHandler:
...

editAssets(assetsid,assettype_assettypeId){ if (GetAssetTypeNameFunction(assettype_assettypeId) === "Tower") { this.props.history.push(/add-assetstower/${assetsid}/${this.props.match.params.sitemasterid}); }]

...
----- Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. I am responding to a onClick in a list to route to a specific component based on the function $
How do I get around this?

Comment: eh, === looks at both type and value. Is `<GetAssetTypeNameComponent datafromparent = {assettype_assettypeId}/>` a string? it looks like a component to me.

Comment: @Kevin B 
GetAssetTypeName is a component.  Does it have to be a function that returns a String to work correctly? I figured since it displayed a String when rendered that a component would return a string. Wrong?

Comment: well, the conditional doesn't call what is on the left hand side, it simply says, are they the same. They are not, in this case.

Answer (score 2):

A component renders content to be displayed in the page. The retuned value of rendering a component is a tree of nodes that contain your content.  All this means that `<GetAssetTypeNameComponent>` may contain the text content `Tower`, but it is not equal to the string `"Tower"`. It just doesn't make any sense to render a component as the test for a conditional like this.

In React you want to use logic to tell react how to render. You ***do not*** want to render and then use the result in your logic.

It's hard to give advice on the best way to fix that with so little code, but maybe you want a a simple function to coverts the id into some text for you.

```
function getAssetName(id) {
  return someLogicSomewhere(id).result.orWhatever
}
```

And now you can do something like:

```
if (getAssetName(assettype_assettypeId) === 'Tower')
{ 
    this.props.history.push(
      `/add-assetstower/${assetsid}/${this.props.match.params.sitemasterid}`
    );
}
```

Comment: @ Kevin B 
I will try to refactor my component into a function that returns a string. I have only created components up to this point. This is a good as time as any to give it a try.

Easy for you, will take me 4 hours the first time....

Component Code now listed in original post.

Comment: @Kevin B
OK...took a shot for an hour at creating a function (see main message for effort and current errors).  I think I am close.  Any assistance in fixing the code would greatly be appreciated. Once I get the hang of the function syntax I will be good to go !

Comment: @HighwayRob there's a lot of things wrong with the code you posted that it's hard to know where to start. And it's bit too much for a stack overflow post. I would recommend studying up on some basics. Like how to use state and props in a react application. Then look into async/await programming and how to query external services. Then you can combine those two things to get what you want here. Good luck!